# FileInputStream.read throws java.io.IOException: Result too large

Tags: java, xml, inputstream, ioexception

I have a temp file

```
File myTmpFile = File.createTempFile( prefix, suffix );
```

which represents a xml that was exported via

```
Preferences.exportSubtree(OutputStream);
```

Now i want to import this file with:

```
Preferences.importPreferences( new FileInputStream( myTmpFile ));
```

But the Stream throws an IOException with the Message("Result too large").
What does this mean? How can I fix this?

```
java.io.IOException: Result too large
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Native Method)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(XMLEntityManager.java:2932)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:704)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at java.util.prefs.XmlSupport.loadPrefsDoc(XmlSupport.java:233)
at java.util.prefs.XmlSupport.importPreferences(XmlSupport.java:182)
at java.util.prefs.Preferences.importPreferences(Preferences.java:1236)
at MyPreferences.importPrefs(MyPreferences.java:322)
```

```
public static void importPrefs(File file){
    FileInputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        java.util.prefs.Preferences.importPreferences( is );
    } catch( FileNotFoundException e ) {
    } catch( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch( InvalidPreferencesFormatException e ) {
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch( IOException e ) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post the complete stack trace ? and also the code for `importPreferences()` ? I guess the problem lies in the `importPreferences()` method.

Comment: there is no stacktrace in the IOException from the native method. `RewindableInputStream` in line 2932 throws the Exception by accessing.

Comment: `importPreferences()` also is a native method ? If not post the code. The problem lies in the way `InputStreams` are being used in `importPreferences()` method

Comment: no, the exception comes from native method, `FileInputStream.read()`. `importPreferences()` is from the `java.util.prefs.Preferences`

Comment: write a print statement in the `IOException` `catch` block, just to make sure ! The javadoc for `Preferences.importPreferences()` says `Throws: 
IOException - if reading from the specified input stream results in an IOException.`

Comment: I updated the code and stacktrace.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8960/discussion-between-rakesh-and-oliholz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I parsing it by myself. Using the `org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS`.
But I needed to copy the `EntityResolver` from `java.util.prefs.XmlSupport` which java uses in the `java.util.prefs.Preferences`. And it works.

```
InputStream parsingStream = new FileInputStream(file)
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

builder.setEntityResolver(new Resolver());
Document doc = builder.parse( parsingStream );

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    
DOMImplementationLS domImplementationLS = (DOMImplementationLS)doc.getImplementation().getFeature( "LS", "3.0" );
LSOutput lsOutput = domImplementationLS.createLSOutput();
lsOutput.setByteStream( outputStream );
LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementationLS.createLSSerializer();
lsSerializer.write( doc, lsOutput );
byte[] byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();


ByteArrayInputStream importStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( byteArray );
Preferences.importPreferences( importStream );
```

---

```
/**
 * For loading an XML document from specified input stream, which must have the requisite DTD URI.
 * @see java.util.prefs.XmlSupport.Resolver
 */
private static class Resolver implements EntityResolver {
    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String pid, String sid)
        throws SAXException {
        if (sid.equals(PREFS_DTD_URI)) {
            InputSource is;
            is = new InputSource(new StringReader(PREFS_DTD));
            is.setSystemId(PREFS_DTD_URI);
            return is;
        }
        throw new SAXException("Invalid system identifier: " + sid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the InputStream hasn't been closed before attempting to read from it.